# Extract one file from multiple zip files

Tags: shell-script, zip

I have a folder tree which contains multiple .zip folders (approx 600) each containing four files.  I wish to extract just one file from each folder and copy it out to a separate folder. To complicate things, the file has the same name in each folder.Is there a script i can run to do this?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you recognize the correct file? By content, file size or date?

Comment: it is by file name, the file has the same name in each folder.

Comment: But if the file has the same name in each folder, then how do you recognize the correct file, after extracting? By folder name?

Comment: @alexander , each folder represents a date. eg: 20150301 and the file is a standard name such as log1.gz.  I'm ultimately trying to amalgamate the contents of files for analyses.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
mkdir -p "DESTDIR"
for i in *.zip ; do
         unzip "$i" "THEFILE" -d "DESTDIR"
         mv "DESTDIR/THEFILE" "DESTDIR/$(basename "$i" .zip)_THEFILE"
done
```

Replace `DESTDIR` with the destination path. And `THEFILE` with the filename of the
the file in each .zip file which you wan to extract.
The files are renamed according to the filename of the zip file.

Comment: jofel, thanks for quick response.  It may be my poor scripting knowledge but I can't get that to work.  Here is an example of my folder structure:         -> top_folder  -> folder1 (...n)  / file1.gz, file2.gz, file3.gz       I want to extract file1 only from each folder and use it's contents in analyses later.

Comment: @Phil Do you have .zip or .gz or .tar.gz files? It seems that your question was not clear in this point. Please edit it. Make a short example with the current situation and the final situation you want.

Comment: @Phil: jofel's answer is correct for the question as posed. If you need something else, your question needs to be different. You do realize that `"THEFILE"` in his answer is a kind of variable that you are supposed to replace, such as with `file1.gz` in your case, right?

Comment: @jofel  sorry for confusion.  This is inhered data so I'm trying to make sense of it.  The top folder seems to be an archive.  Listing it in a terminal, it shows up as "FolderName.zip"  When I navigate to the next level I have a list of folders and in each, there are a number of files with a .gz extension.  It is for example "file1.gz" which I want to extract and output to another folder.  thanks

Comment: @Phil: So are you saying you just just one Zip file, containing many `*.gz` files, collected into sub-folders? That is, `FolderName.zip` → `dir1/file1.gz`, `dir1/file2.gz`, etc., then `dir2/file1.gz`, `dir2/file2.gz`, etc? Also, is this an actual zip file, or a directory named `FolderName.zip`?

Comment: @warren young , it is an actual zip file.

Comment: @Phil: I asked two questions, but you only answered one. How *many* zip files? One for each `file1.gz`, or just one zip file containing all of the nested `file1.gz` files?

Comment: @warren There is one foldername.zip and within that, multiple folders that contain the nested file1.gz files.

Answer (score 1):

[Info-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info-ZIP)'s `unzip` program can recognize [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) in file names. Therefore, if you have a zip file with many files called `file1.gz` in different folders:

```
$ unzip FolderName.zip '*/file1.gz'
Archive:  FolderName.zip
 extracting: FolderName/b/c/file1.gz          
 extracting: FolderName/b/e/file1.gz          
 extracting: FolderName/b/f/file1.gz
```

This despite the fact that `FolderName.zip` also contains files named things *other* than `file1.gz`. If you can match the desired file with a glob pattern, `unzip` can extract it.

I get the impression from your other commentary that you need to concatenate all of these extracted files. Something like this will do what you want, assuming the top-level folder containing the `unzip` output is called `FolderName`, and the target file (`file1.gz`) is at the same folder depth in all subfolders:

```
$ gzcat FolderName/*/*/file1.gz > one-big-uncompressed-log-file
```

That is, it skips over two subfolder levels to pull out the `file1.gz` files, then uncompresses and concatenates them with the common `gzcat` program, found most everywhere you find `gzip` support.

Comment: This looks like what I need,  I'll not get back to it for a couple of hours but will let you know how I get on.  Many thanks. Phil

Comment: Looks like I have not made this easy for myself.  I'm trying to do this process on a SQLServer platform.  The terminal command line does not recognise Unzip.  I have installed the cyqwin terminal and it recognises gunzip but will not accept wildcards "*" so I'll need to spend some time getting a zip application installed and try again. Is there any you recommend to install or avoid?

Comment: @Phil: Re: "it recognises gunzip". `gunzip` is not the same thing as `unzip`. Re-run Cygwin's `setup.exe` and install `unzip`.

Comment: @Phil: Re: "will not accept wildcards" This is either the same confusion as above (`gunzip` vs `unzip`) or you are trying to run Cygwin commands through PowerShell or `cmd.exe`. Use the Cygwin Terminal, which runs Bash by default, which has the same quoting and wildcard processing behavior as a Linux box.

Comment: @Phil: Re: "any you recommend to install or avoid" Don't bother with anything that you can't install via Cygwin's `setup.exe`. Third-party native-Windows utilities will not play well with Cygwin.

Comment: Once again @Warren, thanks for the insight.  Yes, I'm confusing the applications, ignorance really.  I'll rerun the setup.exe as advised.